# Use custom font only if current one has not certain characters

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, font-family, unicode-range

I am working on a script that puts some text on a page. The text contains some unicode characters. I have custom font that has those characters, but I'd like to use my font only if the font used on a webpage does not have them. I can't controll *main* font of the page. I thought of something like this, but it does not work:

`.someclass {
  font-family: inherit, 'myFont';
}`

What's the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: fontname;
    src: url(address.ttf);
}
```